# Ebean play2 delete javax.persistence.PersistenceException ... Unknown column

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

i already done somme delete with my model but one use wrong column name

```
GroupeCours gc = GroupeCours.find
            .where()
            .eq("id",id)
            .findUnique();
GroupeCours gc2 = new GroupeCours();
gc2.id=10L;     
gc2.nom="testbidon";

EbeanServer server = Ebean.getServer("refens");
server.insert(gc2);
server.update(gc); //is ok 
server.delete(gc); //fail
```

GC  Class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="GroupeCours", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "nom", "anneeVersion", "idComposante" }),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "id", "anneeVersion", "idComposante" }) })
public class GroupeCours extends AbstractModel {
/**
 * Clé primaire
 */
@Id
@Column(name="id")
public Long id;
```

The error detaisl is

```
play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[PersistenceException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'GroupeCours_id' in 'where clause']]
```

why is looking for keys GroupeCours_id?
Note: insert and update run well

Answer (score 0):

i have found  my error 
the messages is not really hepfull and make me look on the bad direction
in fact i have somme relation many to many and the error comme from it 
here you see the correct one
i have put the tag @JoinTable
My model comme from play.1.0 and hybernate
the naming convention change a lot beetween hybernate and ebean alsos you have to tague each table and field ...
you can see all the detaisl on
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=fr&fromgroups=#!topic/ebean/b4DRSxY68uM

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="groupes")       
@JoinTable (
           name="VolumeHoraireAEncadrer_GroupeCours",
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "groupes_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "VolumeHoraireAEncadrer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}

       )
public Set<VolumeHoraireAEncadrer> vhae = new HashSet<VolumeHoraireAEncadrer>();
```